# halving an infinite projection in a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

When reading the proof the (iii) and (iv), I was confused the statement which is marked red.

According to the condition in (iii), we know that $\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)$ is infinite, but it may not be properly infinite, we cannot use the "halving" lemma to get the decomposition.

1.How to decompose $\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)$ into the sum of two infinite projections?

2.How to decompose $A$ as the direct sum of $A'$ and $\|B\|Q$?
If we view $A$ as a matrix,
How to prove $A=\begin{bmatrix}
  A' &   & &  \\
   &   &  &\|B\|Q
  \end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a projection $P$ is infinite, then it has a proper subprojection $P_1$ with $P_1\sim P$. In particular $P_1$ is infinite and it has a proper subprojection $P_2\sim P_1$. Continuing this way you get a chain of proper subprojections
$$
P\geq P_1\geq P_2\geq P_3\geq\cdots
$$
Let $R=\bigwedge P_j$, and $R_j=P_j-P_{j+1}$. Then
$$
P=R+\sum_j R_j=\bigg(R+\sum_{j\ \text{ odd}}R_j\bigg)+\bigg(\sum_{j\ \text{ even}}R_j\bigg)
$$
is a sum of two infinite projections.

Knowing that $\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=P+Q$ with both infinite, we can write $$A\,\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=\|A\|_e\,\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=\|A\|_e\,P\oplus \|A\|_eQ.$$
Then
$$
A=\overbrace{A\,\chi_{\sigma(A)\setminus\{\|A\|_e\}}(A)+\|A\|_e\,P}^{A'}+\|A\|_e\,Q.
$$
And because $P$ is infinite, $\|A'\|_e=\|A\|_e$.

---

Since the $\{P_n\}$ are decreasing, $\lim_{\rm sot}P_n=R$. Then
$$
P-R=R_1+P_1-R=R_1+R_2+P_2-R=\cdots=\sum_{j=1}^nR_j+P_n-R\xrightarrow[\rm sot]{}\sum_{j=1}^\infty R_j. 
$$

Comment: 1.How to check that $P=R+\sum_j R_j$?

Comment: 2.If  $\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=P+Q$, we have $A\,\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=\|A\|_e\,\chi_{\{||A||_e\}}(A)=\|A\|_e\,P+ \|A\|_eQ$, why $\|A\|_e\,P\oplus\|A\|_eQ$?. According to the Conway's book, $A\oplus B$ are viewed as a diagonal operator matrix with diagonal elements $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I edited 1 in. As for 2. $PQ=0$ by construction.